# Finding coordinates of a point inside a square using angles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, nonlinear-system

Suppose a square of side length $12$. The square has vertices at coordinates $(0,0), (12,0), (0,12), (12,12)$. Inside the square is a point $a$ with all angles known (from point $a$ to any two vertices). You have to find the coordinates of the point.

You tried to solve this by writing a non-linear set of equations using law of cosines.

$x^2+y^2-2xy\cdot \cos\alpha-12^2=0$
$y^2+z^2-2yz\cdot \cos\beta-12^2=0$
$z^2+w^2-2zw\cdot \cos\gamma-12^2=0$
$w^2+x^2-2wx\cdot \cos\delta-12^2=0$

Where $x,y,z,w$ are distances from point $a$ to the vertices and $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ are the angles between point $a$ and two vertices.

You try to solve this numerically but find out that the matrix is singular. Sometimes you get a good approximation, but sometimes the approximation is just wrong. Depends a lot on the initial guess.

You think of another way to solve this, or you resign.

Comment: why is the problem phrased to weirdly?

Comment: I think you are missing some information.

Comment: This is all the information you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the equation of circle $a$, passing through $A=(0,0)$, $B=(12,0)$ and 
$(6, 6\cot(\alpha/2))$ (I'm supposing $\alpha$ is the angle facing side $AB$):
$$
x^2 + y^2 -12 x - 6 \left(\cot{\alpha\over2} - \tan{\alpha\over2}\right) y =0.
$$
Every point $P$ of that circle, inside the square, has the property that $\angle APB=\alpha$.

Then find the equation of circle $b$, passing through $A=(0,0)$, $D=(0,12)$ and 
$(6\cot(\beta/2),6)$ (I'm supposing $\beta$ is the angle facing side $AD$):
$$
x^2 + y^2 -12 y - 6 \left(\cot{\beta\over2} - \tan{\beta\over2}\right) x =0.
$$
Every point $P$ of that circle, inside the square, has the property that $\angle APD=\beta$.

The point you are seeking is the other intersection (different from $A$) of circles $a$ and $b$. Here's the final result:
$$
\begin{align}
x &=
{24 \cos(\alpha + \beta) \sin\beta (\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha)
\over
\cos 2 \alpha + \cos 2 \beta + \sin 2 \alpha + \sin 2 \beta  - 
 \sin 2(\alpha + \beta)-2};\\
\\
y &=
{24 \cos(\alpha + \beta) \sin\alpha (\sin\beta-\cos\beta)
\over
\cos 2 \alpha + \cos 2 \beta + \sin 2 \alpha + \sin 2 \beta  - 
 \sin 2(\alpha + \beta)-2}.\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Don't really understand the whole process yet, but it works!